# DNSSEC validation failure

Tags: domain, dnssec

My provider transfered domain `salonasruna.com`, but it looks like it's not working properly.

https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/salonasruna.com shows status.

How to solve the problem and the following problems caused by it?

1. I cannot generate Let's Encrypt certificates.
2. I also have a problem with domain propagation.
   About 80 hours have passed and the propagation status looks like this:

   [image: Propagation map]

Comment: What's not working? Dnssec?

Comment: I updated description

Answer (score 1):

The report from VeriSign [DNSSEC Debugger](https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/salonasruna.com) is quite clear: DNSSEC is enabled and the parent zone `.com` has `DS` records, but the zone `salonasruna.com` is not DNSSEC signed (No `DNSKEY`/`RRSIG`s found).

[image: DNSSEC Debugger salonasruna.com]

The [DNSViz](https://dnsviz.net/d/salonasruna.com/dnssec/) shows the same but might be easier to undestand.

[image]

> - `com` to `salonasruna.com`: No valid `RRSIG`s made by a key corresponding to a `DS` RR were found covering the `DNSKEY` RRset, resulting in no secure entry point (SEP) into the zone. (`91.227.122.50`, `91.227.123.50`, `UDP_-_EDNS0_4096_D_KN`, `UDP_-_EDNS0_512_D_KN`)
> - `com` to `salonasruna.com`: The DS RRset for the zone included algorithm `13` (`ECDSAP256SHA256`), but no `DS` RR matched a `DNSKEY` with algorithm `13` that signs the zone's `DNSKEY` RRset. (`91.227.122.50`, `91.227.123.50`, `UDP_-_EDNS0_4096_D_KN`, `UDP_-_EDNS0_512_D_KN`)

At this point, you should **disable DNSSEC to make the DNS work again**. Then, you could sign the zone at the new provider and add the corresponding `DS` records to the parent zone `.com`.

Also, **DNS does not propagate but it is cached**. DNSSEC-aware resolvers will not cache records not passing the validation, no matter how long you wait for "propagation".

Comment: > At this point, you should disable DNSSEC to make the DNS work again.
How it can be done, and who can do it.
My domain provider to whom the domain was transferred?
My old provider?

Comment: It must be done at the registrar (`Registrar: PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com`).